# addeventlistener function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

I am not able to see the data in firebase database after giving the input through UI. Can anyone please help?

```
<body>
  <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Name"><br/>
  <input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Message"><br/>
  <button id="post">Send</button><br/>
  <div id="results"></div>
  <script>
    var myFirebase = new Firebase('https://webchat-a778f.firebaseio.com/');
    var usernameInput = document.getElementByID("username");
    var textInput = document.getElementByID("text");
    var postButton = document.getElementByID("post");

    postButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      myFirebase.push(usernameInput + " says: " + textInput);
      textInput.value = "";
    },false);
```

Comment: Any error on your browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error

It should be

```
document.getElementById
```

The last d is in lowercase